# Tensorflow ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)

Tags: tensorflow

The input layer takes the shape of (128,128,1) i.e., single channel images:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(128,128,1))
```

The model is fed from the generators for train and test sets as follows:

```
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(PATH))
ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(PATH.parent/ 'test'/'*.png'))

ds_train = (ds_train.map(load_augment,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
            .shuffle(578)
            .batch(batch_size))

ds_test = ds_test.shuffle(144).batch(batch_size)
```

The mapping function `load_augment()` is given below:

```
@tf.function()
def load_augment(image_file)
  image1, image2 = load(image_file) # loads using tf.io and returns two images
  image1, image2 = resize(image1, image2, 128, 128) # resizes pairs of images
  if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
     image1 = tf.image.flip_left_right(image1) #flips the images
     image2 = tf.image.flip_left_right(image2)
  image1, image2 = resize(image1, image2, img_size[0]+20, img_size[1]+20)
  image1, image2 = random_crop(image1, image2) # random-crops to get a pair of images of 128x128
  return image2, image2
```

The model is compiled and trained as

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("a_name.h5")
]

epochs = 200
model.fit(ds_train, epochs=epochs, 
          validation_data=ds_test, 
          callbacks=callbacks) # ds_test is the test dataset shown above
```

This throws the error **after running for the first epoch**:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)

I will appreciate if anyone can help.

**More information:**

The the functions `resize()` and `random_crop()` writes tensors as they use tf.image tools.

I checked the shapes of the tensors in the generator as follows:

```
ds = ds_train.take(1)
iter_ds = iter(ds)
ds1 = next(iter_ds)
ds1[0].shape # returns TensorShape([4, 128, 128, 1])
ds1[1].shape # returns TensorShape([4, 128, 128, 1])
```

Comment: Hi Malik, could you share the code of the model definition?

Comment: Hi Sascha, the issue was in the generator for test dataset. I have answered my own question below

Answer (score 1):

The issue got solved when I applied a mapping function, `load()` on the test set. So, I changed the the line `ds_test = ds_test.shuffle(144).batch(batch_size)` by

```
ds_test = (ds_test.map(load,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
            .shuffle(144)
            .batch(batch_size))
```

Without the mapping function `load()`, the test set was containing only filenames and not pairs of images it is supposed to have had.

The function `load()` was written such that it acted on each element of the test dataset and loaded the files and spilt them into to pairs of images.